# Would a fork occur if a half of entire nodes use different block validation algorithm?

Tags: blockchain

Let's assume, a half of entire nodes use different block validation algorithm against the other half. So, for a particular type of block, one accepts it, and another one does not.

Then would the blockchain be forked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would indeed create a hard fork, where the nodes that started using the different algorithm would begin rejecting blocks from those that didn't switch.  Because these nodes are only accepting blocks from other nodes with the different algorithm, they would begin building mined blocks only sent by those nodes (assuming the nodes are also mining).

The blockchain would be forked, and each group of nodes would share the block history up until the block they forked.  This is a 51% attack, but it is highly unlikely on the main chain.